# Motion of a person on the surface of Earth in absence of Earth's attraction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

If the earth suddenly stops attracting objects near its surface, what will be the motion of a person on the surface of the earth? (neglect the effect of rotation of earth.)
There are two possibilities:

1. the person flies along a tangent to Earth's surface.
2. he remains standing.

My book says that the person should remain standing.
But according to me,a particle requires centripetal force to perform circular motion. And  since there is no centripetal force, the person should fly along the tangent to the surface.
Why does my book say so?

Comment: Question formulation (v2) seems contradictory as it simultaneous talks about  _"perform circular motion"_  and _"neglect the effect of rotation of earth"._ So which is it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't ask a question like "what happens to people on a spinning ball if gravity stops (but ignore rotation of the earth)". You're making a question that seems very silly.

If you factor in the rotational effects, he flies off at a tangent.

If you imagine a stationary Earth, the man would 'float' where he was standing previously.

Comment: That man wouldn't "float" for long.  The earth's atmosphere would also "float" away.